# Set timeout for input (cin)

Tags: c++, input, timeout

I'm having some trouble with setting time out for `cin>>`.

After 5 seconds, if the user didn't input anything, skip this `cin>>` and do the next line.

I tried using threads but I can't skip this `cin>>`. The `cin` thread is still running until it got an input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set timeout for std::cin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053175/is-it-possible-to-set-timeout-for-stdcin)

Answer (score -1):

I believe this should work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(){
    int a;
    unsigned t0=time(0);
    std::cin >>a;
    unsigned elapsed=time(0)-t0;
    std::cout <<elapsed<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It is not the correct answer. Your code just print the time that the user spends to enter an integer.