# Stop if reading a file takes more than 5 minutes (C++ std::ifstream)

Tags: c++

I don't have my own code because I don't even know how to start, sorry. I can't find anything about `std::ifstream` file read and how to implement a timer.

I want to read a list of movies and if reading this file takes more than 5 minutes I want it to stop and `std::cout` that it takes too long. How to implement a timer in `std::fstream`?

Comment: Seems very similar to: [Setting a timeout on ifstream in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/575070/2665890)

Comment: To start, for such a "rough" time, you could probably just use a normal c time() and difftime() functions.   Read the movies from the list in a loop and check the elapsed time each pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::async`. It returns a [`future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) object, on which you can `wait_for` specified maximum time interval.

```
std::ifstream file;
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [&file]{ file.open("path/to/file"); });

auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::minutes(5));
if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
    std::cout << "timeout\n";
    return 1;
}
```

`std::launch::async` means a new thread will be used.

Comment: It's not so simple. The future object needs to finish its operation. You won't return from function unless this object finishes its destructor, which will be wait for operation to finish. And in case of file read operation you can't break it. Even closing the file doesn't break the read operation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider solving the problem without timers.

Start by recording the current time. Then read the file chunk by chunk (i.e. not in a single call, but with a loop that reads a part of it). For every chunk, process it and then check the elapsed time with respect to the start. If it is bigger than your threshold, bail out.

In pseudocode:

```
t0 = time();
for (;;) {
    chunk = read();
    if (eof)
        success();

    process(chunk);

    t = time();
    if (t - t0 > timeout)
        error();
}
```